# Change Stylesheet from User-Defined Values using Node

Tags: css, node.js, sass

I am trying to make a web app where the user can change the default values in the stylesheet. I want to have a form that takes user input, such as preferred font and colors, and update the stylesheet with the values given.
I'm using SCSS to style the page. As an example, the stylesheet has the following default variables:

```
$danger: #F4522A;
$warning: #62F500;
$info: #0AA9FF;
```

When the user goes to the settings page and fills out the change color format form, the server then updates the values, so that it takes on the user's preferred color. So if the user enters #0F263D, #0AA9FF, and #85D4FF for danger, warning, and info respectively, the stylesheet will update to

```
$danger: #0F263D;
$warning: #0AA9FF;
$info: #85D4FF;
```

Is there a way to do this with SCSS and Node? I know that SCSS is a preprocessor and you use the compiled CSS for the actual site, so if it's not possible to do this, is there a way to do something like a search and replace for the color values using Node?

Edit: A comment said that this was a frontend question that can be achieved using client-side JavaScript, however, my goal is to update the actual style.sass file so that the color values are updated across all pages permanently. Client-side JavaScript, to my knowledge, only updates the page temporarily.

A solution I've tried is to make a _user_variables.sass file that Node can write the values for, however, this will not update the css file in the server as it needs to be compiled first.

Comment: This is more a front-end requirement, node not withstanding, you can just do this in the client side in javascript. Also, can you show any of the work you've tried ?

Comment: Its important to read :  [ask]